# How can I remove the time in a date/time field in Tableau?

Tags: datetime, tableau-api

I have a date-time field like `22-JUL-19 07.45.43.717000 PM` and I would like to strip the time portion, so I only have the date part. How can I do this in Tableau? I cannot change the way this date-time field is formatted, as it was given to me in this manner.

Thanks!

I saw some stuff online that says you can just deselect the "show times" box in the range of dates filter, but for whatever reason, that is not there for me, so I need to seek an alternative method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the data type of your field in Tableau from date-time to date. You can do that by right clicking on the field in the data pane.

That doesn't change your source data - Tableau never does that as it is a read-only viewer - Changing the data type simply changes how Tableau views the data.

An alternate shortcut is to click on the data type icon next to the field name and select the data type you wish. You'll be changing from an icon with a watch on top of a calendar to just a calendar page to change from data-time to date

Answer (score 0):

When you look at the main data pane, you can right click on the columns to change the data type. Hopefully this solves your problem!